# C# how to create a generic type argument

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

I have existing test code which needs to be extended.

I would like to keep this as generic as possible in order to reduce code duplication, here is a simplified snippet of the current code:

```
    public class FilterValueOne { }

    [TestClass]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void FilterValueOne_TestMethod()
        {
            ManipulateData(BuildFilter());
        }

        private void ManipulateData(FilterValueOne filter)
        {
            // Do some stuff with filter
        }

        private FilterValueOne BuildFilter()
        {
            var filter = new FilterValueOne();
            // Initialize filter data members here...
            return filter;
        }
    }
```

This works, but it is limited to the "FilterValueOne" type.

I want to expand this and make it more generic by implementing a generic type argument.

The code snippet below is what I am after:

```
    // Enum will expand as the app grows
    public enum TypeEnum
    {
        ValueOne,
        ValueTwo,
        ValueThree
    }

    // More classes will be added as the app grows
    public class FilterValueOne { }
    public class FilterValueTwo { }
    public class FilterValueThree { }

    [TestClass]
    public class TestClassGeneric
    {
        // _filter to be used as the generic type argument
        private object _filter;

        // Constructor
        public TestClassGeneric(TypeEnum val)
        {
           switch (val)
           {
               case TypeEnum.ValueOne:
                   _filter = GetTestObject<FilterValueOne>();
                   break;
               case TypeEnum.ValueTwo:
                   _filter = GetTestObject<FilterValueTwo>();
                   break;
               case TypeEnum.ValueThree:
                   _filter = GetTestObject<FilterValueThree>();
                   break;
               default:
                   _filter = null;
                   break;
           }
        }

        private T GetTestObject<T>()
          where T : class
        {
           // Code simplified
           object returnValue = new object();
           return (T)returnValue;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Generic_FilterValue_TestMethod()
        {
            // Error: The type _filter could not be found. (However it exists)
            ManipulateData(BuildFilter<_filter>());
        }

        private void ManipulateData<T>(T filter)
        {
            // Do some stuff with filter
        }    

        private T BuildFilter<T>()
         where T : class
        {
            // I want filter to be dynamically assigned to whatever _filter was
            // assigned to in the constructor (FilterValueOne/Two/Three), instead 
            // of "FilterValueOne"

            var filter = typeof(T);

            // Initialize filter data members here...

            return filter;
        }
    }
```

I ultimately want to use "_filter" as a generic type argument in my test method, but I can't get it to work. I receive an error stating that "_filter could not be found".

I have tried multiple ways of using typeof(_filter) etc. but no success.

I don't understand generics and its potential fully, I don't know if this is even possible or if I'm simply missing something.

Comment: Why is `_filter` a static? Note that `new object()` is completely worthless...

Comment: `private T GetTestObject<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            return new T();
        }` You can add a `new()` constraint so that you can create new instances of `T` in your generic methods. Maybe this will help? I don't quite see why you have a `static object _filter`, though.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to put too much logic into test classes. They should be as simple as possible. Another person should see its intention at first sight and there should be definitive no need to test the test code.

Comment: @NetMage thanks for pointing out the static issue, it doesn't make sense so I removed it. I initialized it with "new object()" to conform to existing coding standards in the project.

Comment: @RufusL Thank you.. Could you please elaborate on the usage of the GetTestObject method with the new() constraint as suggested? I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 2):

The `T` in `BuildFilter<T>` is a type parameter. You are passing an instance of a type, in your case an instance of `object` (aka `System.Object`) not a type.

You simply cannot do that, hence the compiler error (`_filter` is *not* a type; it's an instance and that's why the compiler can't find that "type").

What you want to do instead is instantiate a specific `BuildFilter<FilterValueOne>`, etc. and create tests that test each of these things.

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void Generic_FilterValueOne_TestMethod()
{
    ManipulateData(new BuildFilter<FilterValueOne>());
}
```

It looks like you're using MS Test; AFAIK MS Test does not support generic tests, so you will have to create a test for each type you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you @Kit, I realise what I want will circumvent the proper way to test things. However I still believe there should be a way to do this when not in a testing scenario. I'm having a generics problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use generic test class, but if you prefer to pass filter type through contructor or as a method parameter you can use `Activator` class.

```
public class TestClassGeneric<T> where T : new()
{
    public void Generic_FilterValue_TestMethod()
    {
        var filter = new T();
        // ManipulateData(filter);
    }
}

public class TestClassConstructorArg
{
    private readonly Type type;

    public TestClassConstructorArg(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void Generic_FilterValue_TestMethod()
    {
        var filter = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        // var filter = Activator.CreateInstance(type, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, arguments...);
        // ManipulateData(filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @opewix, this is more like the solution I'm looking for but implementation is problematic.. I believe my use case doesn't allow me to do what I want, however to implement it in non-test case should be viable.